# Is there a way to filter log4j logs for a particular category

Tags: java, logging, file-io, log4j

I have a requirement to collate all **log4j** logs belonging to a few categories and send out a mail at the end of each day. As I am logging all categories into the same (dated) file using *org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender*, I am unable to figure out a way to filter the generated logs without reading through the log file. It'd be great if somebody could suggest me a way to do this using **java**. Following code is a sample of some of the categories of logs I need to filter.

```
log.fatal("Fatal error message");
log.error("Error message");
```

If filtering in the end isn't possible, it should be enough if I can at least find a way to override the functions for these categories. My log4j.properties looks like this.

```
log =/usr/end_of_day_logs
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE

log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log}/log.out
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.FILE.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm} [%C %x~ %M:%L] %-5p - %m%n
```

Comment: Please don't miss the option to use log4j 2 - beta, but already very stable. It gives you a lot more filtering options than log4j 1 series

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create separate files for separate categories and then implement an `Appender` which sends mail. You can take a look at what `DailyRollingFileAppender` does and probably extend it to send the file in a mail.

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple appenders for each log levels[or even for different log packages].

```
log =/usr/end_of_day_logs
log4j.rootLogger = FATAL, FFILE

log4j.appender.FFILE=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FFILE.File=${log}/flog.out
log4j.appender.FFILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.FFILE.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.FFILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FFILE.layout.conversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm} [%C %x~ %M:%L] %-5p - %m%n
```

---

```
log =/usr/end_of_day_logs
log4j.rootLogger = ERROR, EFILE

log4j.appender.EFILE=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.EFILE.File=${log}/elog.out
log4j.appender.EFILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.EFILE.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.EFILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.EFILE.layout.conversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm} [%C %x~ %M:%L] %-5p - %m%n
```

Then use another appender with SMTP appener with required pattern.

```
log4j.appender.MAIL=org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender
log4j.appender.MAIL.BufferSize=1
log4j.appender.MAIL.SMTPHost=smtp.example.com
log4j.appender.MAIL.From=application@example.com
log4j.appender.MAIL.To=developer@example.com
log4j.appender.MAIL.Subject=Exception in Application
log4j.appender.MAIL.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.MAIL.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %5r %-5p [%t] %c{2} - %m%n
```

Comment: Thanks, but this still enforces only one category of logs to be sent out. That too every time there's a log of that category. I wanted a way to send out a set of categories, logs of which are collated and sent all at once. I have implemented this manually for now. Better solutions will be appreciated.